# How to reference an ISO/IEC?

Tags: technical-writing, citations, tools

I'm doing some college work and I'm using ISO/IEC 27000 Information technology — Security techniques — Information security management systems — Overview and vocabulary.

In Word, I have set up the bibliography to use Chicago formatting, Sixteenth Edition. The data I've put in Word are show in the image below.

[image]

It appears like that in the document:

[image]

For me, it's good enough, but is it correct? My only real issue is that when referencing it doesn't show which ISO I'm talking about, just the author and year, just like that:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lectus justo, egestas in cursus quis, convallis eu dolor **(ISO/IEC 2014)**. Aliquam bibendum ligula arcu, vitae blandit purus iaculis at.

As you can see, it doesn't show the ISO number, 27000 and I need that. How can I fix it, is there a better reference style for this kind of document other than Chicago?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the mechanics of Word here but I can help with what the results should look like.

Referenced standards almost always look something like this in references:

ISO/IEC 27000:2014, *Information technology — Security techniques — Information security management systems — Overview and vocabulary*.

if a specific edition is meant (including if specific clauses are referred to). You can leave the year off for normative references (not in your case).

Cited references look like: ISO/IEC 27000:2014, 5.4.

Or: ISO/IEC 27000:2014, Clause 5.

You don't need the month at all, because standards are never revised more than once a year and months are hardly ever mentioned. You quite possibly don't usually need to add the publisher either. International standards are made available by different national standards bodies but unless you need to refer to a national foreword or something it's all the same text inside.

If you want to refer to the standards body, remember it's "International Organization for Standardization" not "International Standardization Organization"...

Word might not be very sympathetic to this style. I remember BiBTeX similarly not cooperating with me.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check on Word, but sadly I think the only workaround to show the cited reference like "ISO/IEC 27000:2014" is to change the "Corporate Author" field to this text. It seems there's no official way, but at least it will show correctly on the document.